# Xamarin Android Data-Binding with MVVM Light

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, mvvm-light

## Original Question:

I have a problem trying to bind a value from my ViewModel to a TextView in Xamarin Android using MVVM Light. The value changes once and then stops working. even though the object changes in the ViewModel and the binding mode is set to the default (OneWay).

Due to business requirements i am required to keep using MVVM Light and Xamarin Android.

Example:
In my first fragment I have a list of books that is bound to a list of books in my ViewModel. In my Viewmodel i have an object named CurrentBook which changes with an onclick event in my list.

```
VM.CurrentBook = Books[index];
```

In my second fragment i have the title bound to a TextView

```
_titleBinding = this.SetBinding(() => VM.CurrentBook.Title, () => TitleTextView.Text);
```

The first time the Current book changes from **NULL** to an instance of **Book** the title changes as desired. After the first time when changing **VM.CurrentBook = Books[index];** the title remains the same as the first seleced book.

---

## Update:

I have tried a couple of things with the help of *Milen Pavlov*,
I tried changing to

```
VM.SetBinding(() => VM.CurrentBook.Title, TitleTextView, () => TitleTextView.Text, BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

This triggerd an error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetException: Object of type '[Solution].Client.Shared.ViewModels.BooksViewModel' doesn't match target type '[Solution].Client.Android.BookDetailsFragment'
```

Another thing i tried:

```
_titleBinding = this.SetBinding(() => VM.CurrentBook.Title, TitleTextView, () => TitleTextView.Text, BindingMode.TwoWay);
enter code here
```

This triggerd another error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetException: Object of type 'Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatTextView' doesn't match target type '[solution].Client.Android.BookDetailsFragment'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this overload when data binding on xamarin android and mvvm-light:

```
VM.SetBinding(() => VM.CurrentBook.Title, TitleTextView, () => TitleTextView.Text, BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: after trying this i got this error: 
`System.Reflection.TargetException: Object of type 'Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatTextView' doesn't match target type 'Sollution.Android.BookDetailsFragment'`

Comment: Are you calling this after `inflater.Inflate(..)` in `OnCreateView()`?

Comment: I still have the same error even after placing the binding on the vm
`System.Reflection.TargetException: Object of type 'sollution.Client.ViewModels.VM' doesn't match target type 'Sollution.Android.BookDetailsFragment'`

Comment: is the type of `sollution.Client.ViewModels.VM` different from the type of `ViewModel` you have in `Sollution.Android.BookDetailsFragment`?

Comment: the VM is of type BookViewModel which inherits from ViewModelBase and Sollution.Android.BookDetailsFragment is of type BookDetailsFragment which inherits from Fragment

Comment: Another important consideration: Is your `BookDetailsFragment` inheriting from `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` or just from `Fragment` ?

Comment: Android.App.Fragment

Comment: Shouldn't you use `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` since `AppCompatTextView` is from the support library? I know it seems unrelated to your issue but it could be causing the exception you're getting...

Comment: I Just removed AppCompat to see if this was the issue, i'll put it back now because this wasn't the fix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102602/discussion-between-jonathan-and-milen-pavlov).

Comment: I have another question, did you link your viewmodel to your fragment? if so, How?

Comment: found a temporary fix, not one i love to keep but it works,            ´VM.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => { SetBindings(); };´

Comment: Either by creating new instance of the view model in you Fragment constructor or by using Dependency Injection framework like Autofac for example...